# SSAS Excluding a dimension from aggregation on a measure

Tags: ssas, mdx

I have the following problem. I have a cube where I want some measures aggregated across all dimensions, but one set of measures should exclude one non-time dimension from aggregation. Specifically I have the following case: A consolidated Premium / Claim fact table containing [Written Premium] and [Loss Incurred]. There are Policy and Claim dimensions. [Loss Incurred] should aggregate across both dimensions, however [Written Premium] should not aggregate over Claims.

Is there a good way to do this with MDX? All of my research has come up blank, only telling me how to set up parent-child hierarchies and Account types. Am I just attempting something that SSAS is not well suited to handle?

Comment: One possible solution has occurred to me. Instead of creating a consolidated fact table, I've simply added my MonthEndLoss and MonthEndPremium tables as separate Measure Groups of a single cube. This seems to give me the behavior close to what I want. Unfortunately it results in occasional null values showing up in my results where dimension combinations valid for one measure group doesn't point to valid data in the other.

Comment: Have you looked into calculated measures?

Comment: "Am I just attempting something that SSAS is not well suited to handle?" ...? I think the opposite is true - this is the sort of thing SSAS was built to handle. Are you admin of the cube or an end user of the cube?